# The missing "to" in the phrase "subject to"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I learned that when referring one thing is subject to another thing, a "to" should always be there next to "subject" or before a which/that, etc. However, in the below language, there is no such "to", but the sentence is still correct. Can anyone tell me why? Many thanks!

> "It is required to do so by law or by the regulations of any relevant
> stock exchange or other regulatory authority the rules and regulations
> of which he or it is subject."

Jack

Comment: The sentence needs a **to** for it to be a grammatically correct one.

Comment: This has been worded with "of" instead of "to." I would probably say "to which he or it is subject."

Comment: Can't just replace that "of" - since "of which" refers to "of the authority".  Looks like the missing "to" will have to just hang off the end, making this unfortunate sentence even longer.

Comment: @cruthers Either that, or _**to** the rules and regulations of which..._ Sounds clumsy that way, though.

Comment: "... the rules and regulations of which he or it is subject **to**.

Comment: In educated English usage the word order is always “the xxxx, below”. (In your question “language” is also unnatural. I’d use “extract”, “citation”, “text” or say what the text you are quoting from is and follow that with “shown below”.) And you should consider posting on English Language Learners.

Answer (score 1):

> *It is required to do so by law or by the regulations of any relevant*
> *stock exchange or other regulatory authority* [*the rules and regulations*
> *of which he or it is subject **to***].

"To" is required.

In the bracketed relative clause "which" refers to "regulations of any relevant stock exchange or other regulatory authority".

We understand that "he or it is subject to those rules and regulations".